# Excel Formulas for two workbooks-multiple criterias

Tags: excel

So I have this huge report and I'm looking to analyze it better. I have Data in one work book (1)and I'm creating a separate workbook (2) to reflect certain criteria.

1. Workbook 1-I have Data in Col A, Col B, Col C.
   Column A has abbreviated businesses (ex. Abc, Def, Ghi)
   Column B has Dates for everyday of last year and this year (ex.1/3/2017)
   Column C has Y or N values.
2. Workbook 2- In work book 2, I need data from the previous month, of a particular business (Abc) with just values equal to Y

Comment: Sorry, I need the sum of total "Y" within those parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should make a pivot table that contains the data you want, and then double click the cell containing the data meeting your criteria and it will pull up the source data for only those criteria. That's a pretty simple way to do it.

i.e. Make a pivot table in Workbook 1 with a month filter, a business filter, and a values equal to Y filter.

EDIT:

I took a stab at it without getting your specifics. Images including formula are attached.

Sheet1 contains the data. Sheet2 calculates the sum for the month for each business.

These are array formulas and require you use ctr+shift+enter to confirm the cell. Then you can drag down for month and business as needed.

`{=SUM(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$43=A2,IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$43>=D2,IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$43<=E2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$43))))}`

NOTE: My sheet1 only went down to row 43, hence the $43 in the equation. You'll need to replace those values with your values.

This also assumes that you are using dates down to the day. If you have a column that is for Months, and it's text, then you can nest an `IF($B$2:$B$43="January", ....` or however you have your months defined.

[image: Sheet1 Data]
[image: Sheet2 Calculations]

Comment: I'm really looking for a formula

Comment: Then we need more information. In Workbook2, which columns do you need from Workbook1? Will the rows still match up (i.e. values in columns A, B, C, D in row 2 of Workbook 1 will still all be in the same row in Workbook1 if the criteria are met). Is there any other rearranging of the data that's occurring in Workbook2

Are you essentially just trying to recreate Workbook1 in Workbook2  using only data that meets your specified conditions?

Comment: Edited and hopefully solved for you. Let me know if not.

Comment: it occurs to me that you might need to add another `IF` statement. If Column C indicates a category Y or N, and column D includes the numeric values to be summed then add a 4th IF statement so the whole equation would be 
`{=SUM(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$43=A2,IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$43>=D2,IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$43<=E2,IFSheet1!$C$2:$C$43="Y",Sheet1!$D$2:$D$43)))))}`